# Highcharts axis padding offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have looked for a particular case for a highchart configuration but cant seem to find any answers.

I want to know is it possible to add some padding on the x axis to put the plotted graph in an arbitrary point on the x axis such that is should look like so:
[Desired Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn7E9.png)

I've tried

```
minPadding: 1,
maxPadding: 1
```

which can condense data towards the middle but I want an empty plot point

Here is a jsFiddle to get most of what I wanted except that padding
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj3j7bye/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This update will add two empty categories

Javascript line 8

```
data: [0,12.5,32.7,45,9.8,0],
```

Javascript lie 13

```
categories: ['','<16', '16-25', '26-35', '>35',''],
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't try a simple work around like this, I will just have to make sure to prefix and suffix my data array with empty values